# What is the difference between an expression, a proposition, and a term?

Tags: terminology

A term serves as an argument for a proposition.  A term may include functions (+,-,x), constants (1, Max, π), and variables (a, b). A term does not form a compete proposition. Accordingly, it cannot express a fact, so it cannot express a relation.

So '(5+a)<9' is a proposition; wherein '(5+a)' is a term, which functions as the argument that saturates the predicate '<9'.

Is the word *expression* just the most general term for a well formed set of symbols, which could apply to terms, equations, and formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *proposition* is less commonly used than *sentence* and *formula*.

It is possible to use the word *expression* to denote something that is either a term or a formula. But there is no real need for the word.

Comment: Can *expression* also be used to refer to the predicate, or to something in the predicate?

Comment: A term is **never** a proposition. To make an analogy with ordinary English, terms are nouns or pronouns, while propositions are sentences.

Comment: Pardon me, that's not what I meant to type. I edited it.

Comment: Unlike *predicate symbol*, or *term*, or *formula*, the word *expression* has no formal meaning, so can be used informally as one wishes, if one wishes. It would however be a very odd thing to refer to the very incomplete "$\forall x(f(x)\lt$" as an expression.